# Can I turn data in google assistant app into file format for upload?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am creating an app for google assistant which will collect data while a user plays a game and then send that data to a project database. The API I am using to sent the data (synapse) requires it to be in file format, however, I can't find a way to create a file for the data due to the nature of google assistant apps. Am I overlooking a way to do this/is there a way to get around this and send the data somewhere else to make it into file format? The data is stored in a JSON object.

Comment: Can you update your question to elaborate on what you mean by "the nature of google assistant apps" that is causing the problem? What have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: From what I can tell, I am unable to create a local file for my data using google assistant apps. If I'm correct, this is because it is an application on the personal assistance device, rather than on a computer. Mind you, this is all just from what I've been able to find. The documentation on it, being fairly new, is certainly sparse.

Answer (score 1):

The conversation that your users have with your Action will be relayed from their Assistant device (such as Google Home) to Google's servers, which do a little processing, and then to your server. Your server is then responsible for sending back a reply to Google's servers, which sends it on to the Assistant device. This is very similar to how a web browser and server work, and for good reason - your server accepts commands via a "webhook", which is just a fancy way of saying that Google's servers contact your server via HTTPS, and you're sending back a reply via HTTPS.

Your webhook can do anything - as long as it does it fast enough. You can store what command the person has issued and either aggregate a number of them into a file format to send, or send each one.

Your Action does not, itself, run on the user's device any more than a web page with a form "runs" on the user's device. It displays there, just like your Action is read out loud... but almost all interaction is sent back to you with minimal processing on the device itself.